# Strange returned value when calling hal_can library function for stm32 when timeout

Tags: c, debugging, stm32, can-bus, hal

I'm using hal can library for stm32L476vg mcu. I'm debugging my can transmission app and I can observe something apparently wrong in HAL_CAN_Transmit() sequence execution and its returned value, specially when it musts return HAL_TIMEOUT value.

Main code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "Pm03_SystemConfig.h"
#include "App_Task_CAN.h"

uint8_t charBuffer[10]={0x00};

int main(void)
{   

   /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */

  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */

  Pm03_SystemClock_Config();
  App_Task_CAN_reset();
  App_Task_CAN_init();
  charBuffer[0]=0xCA;
  charBuffer[1]=0xFE;

  while (1)
  {     
     App_Task_CAN_sendData(&charBuffer[0]);
  }
}
```

My TX higher level function implementation that calls hal_can transmit and init for can configuration in App_Task_CAN.c file:

```
uint8_t App_Task_CAN_sendData(uint8_t* cBuffer)
{ 
   for (uint8_t index=0; index< DATABTXLONG; index ++)
   {
         HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->Data[index]= cBuffer[index];
   }

   if (HAL_CAN_Transmit(&HCAN_Struct, TIMEOUT)!=HAL_OK)
   {
         TaskCan_Error_Handler();
   }
 }

void App_Task_CAN_init(void)
{   

    static CanTxMsgTypeDef        TxMessage;
    static CanRxMsgTypeDef        RxMessage;

    /*configuracion timing para obtener 500kb/s*/ 
    HCAN_Struct.Instance = CAN1;

    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg = &TxMessage;
    HCAN_Struct.pRxMsg = &RxMessage;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;//values defined in different hal libraries
    HCAN_Struct.Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_6TQ;//segment point at 87.5%
    HCAN_Struct.Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.TTCM = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.ABOM = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.AWUM = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.NART = DISABLE;
    HCAN_Struct.Init.RFLM = DISABLE;//Fifo locked mode disabled
    HCAN_Struct.Init.TXFP = DISABLE;//prioridad de tx por id (más bajo más prioridad)

    if (HAL_CAN_Init(&HCAN_Struct) != HAL_OK)
    {
      TaskCan_Error_Handler();
    }
        //TX
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->StdId = 0x321;
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->ExtId = 0x01;//29 bits 
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->IDE   = CAN_ID_STD;//values defined in different hal libraries
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->RTR   = CAN_RTR_DATA;//values defined in different hal libraries
    HCAN_Struct.pTxMsg->DLC   = DATABTXLONG;//1-9

 }
```

some defines used above, declared in App_Task_CAN.h:

```
/* Timeout for can operations in bit time units */

#define TIMEOUT 100

/* param for config mesg frames */

#define DATABTXLONG 2
```

I was debugging and going step by step through all the hal transmit function sequence (concerned piece of code below) and I can see how, after first TXRQ ->

Part of hal_can_transmit function in stm32l4xx_hal_can.c file:

```
   HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_CAN_Transmit(CAN_HandleTypeDef* hcan, uint32_t Timeout)
   {
     ...
     /* Request transmission */
     hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TIR |= CAN_TI0R_TXRQ;
     ...
     /* Check End of transmission flag */
     while(!(__HAL_CAN_TRANSMIT_STATUS(hcan, transmitmailbox)))
     {
       /* Check for the Timeout */
       if(Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)
       {
          if((Timeout == 0) || ((HAL_GetTick()-tickstart) > Timeout))
          {
             hcan->State = HAL_CAN_STATE_TIMEOUT;
             /* Process unlocked */
              __HAL_UNLOCK(hcan);//line in which thread breaks
             return HAL_TIMEOUT;//ignored line during debug
           }
        }
     }
     ...
   }
```

(NOTE: This next piece of code belongs to hal library provided by ST)

-> once the thread passes through the above transmit call, after TXRQ line this happens:

1. the thread waits for end Tx flag and
2. after timeout value expires, the threads goes into timeout state line
3. it arrives until hal unlock() macro line
4. after this, it exits/breaks the execution and returns to the line where this function was called ignoring the next line "return HAL_TIMEOUT".
5. The thread is broken just before arriving to this line (red text line). It returns to my transmit call a HAL_OK value! I recieve HAL_OK value! I confirm this after mounting a switch case in order to see what value it was reciving instead of HAL_TIMEOUT.

It happens from the first time transmit is called. I don't know if it is normal behavior. Obviously it is a hal_can code fact and I can not do anything from code user to fix it.

Has someone else, who worked with hal can for stm32, faced this situation?

My Tx does not work and I was looking for the possible fail causes through debugging. Hence I have seen this. Maybe there is more than this code problem to solve. But I think my code is very simple to fail: I only call send data in a infinite loop (of course after can init). By debugging I can see how data is arriving to the mailboxes correctly, but flag of TXOk never sets.

So, maybe this hal_can strange behavior is part of the cause of my transmission fail.

It seems to be a third party bug. Has someone deal with same situation? Any suggestion about my user code? is there something to improve?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is quite difficult to answer. You need to narrow down the problem even more. I would say that your program is invoking Undefined Behavior due to problems handling pointers somewhere. But it's really difficult to tell with the provided information. Maybe some *stm32*, *hal* or whatever that is expert can help though.

Comment: There is no "stm32L4F6" MCU. You missed part of the name. And as general advice: The STlib/"HAL" is bloatware without any benefit. It does not even provide a true hardware abstraction. Read the reference manual, directly program the registers. Do the abtraction with drivers.

Comment: Note that preparing a [mcve] typically means creating a *new* program exhibiting the misbehavior of interest, not merely cutting out or hiding parts of the program where you discovered the problem.  Either way, be sure that what you present is indeed *complete*; what you have presented so far omits several variable and type declarations that could be relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Olaf the idea was using HAL in order to have  portable code as much as possible. But I'm starting to be agree with you about using these libraries has not any benefit. Specially if this type of bugs has confirmed by st support. What do you mean with do the abstraction "with drivers"? Doing my own drivers or using the lower level driver also provided by st? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Portable to - what? For the STM32, if the modules are the same, the hardware is the same anyway. For other devices, there is no identical HAL (that is some STM proprietary rubbish). You have to learn the hardware-features anyway (and you can't use them if the hardware doesn't support them) - plus the badly documented (if at all) HAL functions, `struct`s, etc. Memory footpront for the `struct`s is ridiculous, plus the code-overhead for filling them just to call a function which transfers them into peripheral registers.

Comment: As I say: define a clean, abstract interface for your drivers (not a unified, but fitting to the problem!), put the hardware-stuff directly into the drivers and never think about the hardware once tested. Oh, and: document the code/interface well, including timing, constraints, interrupt-priority, etc.

Comment: @Olaf for example from stm32 arm m4 based to another stm32 arm m0 based. Thanks for the last suggestion. I have too much to learn from embedded world yet.

Comment: That's not really portable. I the hardware is the same, you canjust use the same peripheral accesses, if not, the "HAL" is also not the same, because you have different features. And the HAL adds overhead, which are a serious problem for interrupt handlers. For EMC and other reason you often let the system run at the lowest clock possibly (with some margin, of course). For power-reduction you want the CPU sleep most of the time, etc.

Comment: Theoretically stm32CubeMX package provides a drivers level layer with HAL libraries for stm32L/F families from arm m0 to arm m4 in order to give portability between different STM32 devices via standardized API calls. This was the reason why I started to code using its HAL lib. But will I take notes from your words.